# Removing seconds from time asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, report, expression

In my report viewer i am using an expression to format and show the date and time but i would like to remove the seconds from the time.

```
=Format(Now())
```

Result

```
2/27/2012 8:30:19 AM
```

Desired Result

```
2/27/2012 8:30 AM
```

Comment: @PranayRana I got this to work but i am not getting AM or PM after time Format(Now().ToString("M/d/yyyy H:mm"))

Comment: Google .Net DateTime formatting, its worth learning how to format strings not just asking.

Comment: @Amina Try DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy H:mm tt"); tt is for AM/PM

Comment: @Lloyd - thanks for the help it worked. I just thought i would ask for a quick answer before spending time reading which will happen.

Comment: hi you can also try String.Format("{0:g}", dt); as i mention in my answer.............

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
=Format(Now().ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mm tt" +" UTC"+ " zzz"))
```

This is how i set my expression for: value and i got the results i needed along with zzz utc time format. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `ToString` [pattern](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) for `DateTime`

```
var dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("d t");
```